# How to send all possible WHERE options to mysqli?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hello everyone I am sending 3 var via **form / select / input** to mysqli_fetch which creates div with another var and put there image which have same id as name.jpg.

**Question :** How to make option **all** for instance in colors to **send all possible colors** to $color_val?

[image]

```
<form action="produkt.php" method="post">
<!-- COLOR-->
<li>
<img class="img_search_bar" src="../img/search/color.jpg" />
    <select id="color" name="color">
      <option value="all" selected="selected">ALL</option>
      <option value="blue">blue</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
      <option value="black">black</option>
      <option value="white">white</option>
    </select>
    </li>
  <!-- 2 more like this for size and type-->
 <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" /></a>  <!-- refresh page-->
 </form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     // Storing Selected Value In Variable
   $color_val = $_POST['color'];
   $size_val = $_POST['size']; 
   $type_val = $_POST['type'];  

// Displaying Selected Value
   echo "COLOR :" .$color_val;  
   echo "<br>SIZE :" .$size_val;
   echo "<br>TYPE :" .$type_val;

//making connection to database
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","" ,"test");
//selecting query from database where var = select var
   $query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE color = '$color_val' AND size ='$size_val' AND type = '$type_val'";

   if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){

/* fetch associative array */
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       printf ("
         <div id='produkt_table'>
          <img class='produkt_ikon' src='../img/produkt/ikon/%s.jpg'>
          <h3> name : name </h3>
          <h4> Prize : %s </h4>
          <h5> Stock : %s </h5>
         </div>         
    ", $row["id"], $row["prize"], $row["stock"]);
    }

/* free result set */
     mysqli_free_result($result);
   }
}
/* close connection  mysqli_close($link);*/
?>
```

Comment: So whats wrong with your code are you getting an error..

Comment: I am not getting error I dont get any result if buttons are set to **ALL** because it send value ALL which is not in database for colors. In case of **ALL** I want that value like it doesnt matter. But how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in place of `$query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE size ='$size_val' AND type = '$type_val' AND ".$Query_appender;`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM testtable";
if($color_val !='all' || $size_val !='all' || $type_val !='all')
{
    $query_arr = array();
    if($color_val !='all')
    {
        $query_arr[] = "color = '$color_val'";
    }
    if($size_val !='all')
    {
        $query_arr[] = "size ='$size_val'";
    }
    if($type_val !='all')
    {
        $query_arr[] = "type = '$type_val'";
    }

    $query .=" where ".implode(" AND ", $query_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**BIG FAT WARNING: YOUR CODE IS INSECURE, SO IS MY EXAMPLE! READ BOTTOM FOR MORE!**

Your description is very vague, but I give it a try.

> $query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE color = '$color_val' AND size ='$size_val' AND type = '$type_val'";

If you want to match all colors when `$color_val === 'ALL'`, you have to make the query conditional.

**Note: this code and your code is INSECURE**

```
if ($color_val === 'ALL' && empty($color_val)) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE size ='$size_val' AND type = '$type_val'";
} else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE color = '$color_val' AND size ='$size_val' AND type = '$type_val'";
}
```

## About that Security-Thing

Your code is open to SQL injection, I suggest you start reading the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on it or simply [google for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20injection).

You don't validate, you don't escape, you could just give away the password to your database as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do. I have made slight changes in your code to get this. You could now optimize this too.

the changes

in html part i have changed the value of option 'all' to 1. this is to easily check the condition in the back end.

The variable $Query_appender is used to store part of the query. if there is a specific color coming through, it will carry the condition else it will carry simply 1.
 now i have modified your query to change the color condition to last and appended the value in the variable.

**This said, if its just the color, you can check the value of the post variable and write two different queries in a conditional statement.**

```
<form action="produkt.php" method="post">
<!-- COLOR-->
<li>
<img class="img_search_bar" src="../img/search/color.jpg" />
    <select id="color" name="color">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">ALL</option>
      <option value="blue">blue</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
      <option value="black">black</option>
      <option value="white">white</option>
    </select>
    </li>
  <!-- 2 more like this for size and type-->
 <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" /></a>  <!-- refresh page-->
 </form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     // Storing Selected Value In Variable
   $color_val = $_POST['color'];
   $size_val = $_POST['size']; 
   $type_val = $_POST['type'];
   $Query_appender = '1';
   if($color_val!=1)
       {
        $query_appender = "color = '$color_val'";}

// Displaying Selected Value
   echo "COLOR :" .$color_val;  
   echo "<br>SIZE :" .$size_val;
   echo "<br>TYPE :" .$type_val;

//making connection to database
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","" ,"test");
//selecting query from database where var = select var
   $query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE size ='$size_val' AND type = '$type_val' AND ".$Query_appender;

   if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){

/* fetch associative array */
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       printf ("
         <div id='produkt_table'>
          <img class='produkt_ikon' src='../img/produkt/ikon/%s.jpg'>
          <h3> name : name </h3>
          <h4> Prize : %s </h4>
          <h5> Stock : %s </h5>
         </div>         
    ", $row["id"], $row["prize"], $row["stock"]);
    }

/* free result set */
     mysqli_free_result($result);
   }
}
/* close connection  mysqli_close($link);*/
?>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Cheers :)